# ERROR Illegal tag name - Vue 3 / Vite does not show origin of error

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, nuxtjs3

I`m facing this error recently using Nuxt 3, but my guess is it's related to Vue 3 and Vite:

[image: ERROR Illegal tag name. Use '<' to print '<'.]

I'm wondering how one is supposed to fix it, if no affected file is mentioned.

Is there any chance to **display the origin**, or do I have to manually look through all of my Vue components?

Comment: You don't have a more specific stacktrace? No ESlint errors on your codebase? Probably missed to close a tag somewhere. Hard to help with just that tho.

Comment: @kissu sry, my bad, but this was indeed everything I got at this point in time. Turned out when running the build command, I got the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, after running `build` I got the log with the component causing this issue.